# How to render a checkbox disabled in jquery grid for a particular cell(Not the entire row)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, struts2-jquery-grid, paramquery

When i am loading the page, some of the checkbox's should be disabled and the user should not be able to select them. For example, when loading the page, checkbox for rows with odd "id" should be disabled. But the entire row should not be disabled, only the checkbox. I have been trying to figure it out for a long time now and i couldn't find any answers. Thanks in advance.
Here is my code.

```
!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <!--jQuery dependencies-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

 <!--ParamQuery Grid files-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="pqgrid.min.css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="pqgrid.min.js" ></script>

 <!--Main javscript file to create the paramquery-->
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
        //state of the checkbox and row selection is being saved in state field.
        var data = [
            { id: 1, company: 'Exxon Mobil', revenues: '339938.0', profits: '36130.0' },
            { id: 2, company: 'Wal-Mart Stores', revenues: '315654.0', profits: '11231.0' },
            { id: 3, company: 'Royal Dutch Shell', revenues: '306731.0', profits: '25311.0' },
            { id: 4, company: 'BP', revenues: '267600.0', profits: '22341.0' },
            { id: 5, company: 'General Motors', revenues: '192604.0', profits: '-10567.0' },
            { id: 6, company: 'Chevron', revenues: '189481.0', profits: '14099.0' },
            { id: 7, company: 'DaimlerChrysler', revenues: '186106.3', profits: '3536.3'},
            { id: 8, company: 'Toyota Motor', revenues: '185805.0', profits: '12119.6' },
            { id: 9, company: 'Ford Motor', revenues: '177210.0', profits: '2024.0' },
            { id: 10, company: 'ConocoPhillips', revenues: '166683.0', profits: '13529.0' },
            { id: 11, company: 'General Electric', revenues: '157153.0', profits: '16353.0' },
            { id: 12, company: 'Total', revenues: '152360.7', profits: '15250.0' },
            { id: 13, company: 'ING Group', revenues: '138235.3', profits: '8958.9' },
            { id: 14, company: 'Citigroup', revenues: '131045.0', profits: '24589.0' },
            { id: 15, company: 'AXA', revenues: '129839.2', profits: '5186.5'},
            { id: 16, company: 'Allianz', revenues: '121406.0', profits: '5442.4' },
            { id: 17, company: 'Volkswagen', revenues: '118376.6', profits: '1391.7' },
            { id: 18, company: 'Fortis', revenues: '112351.4', profits: '4896.3' },
            { id: 19, company: 'Crédit Agricole', revenues: '110764.6', profits: '7434.3' },
            { id: 20, company: 'American Intl. Group', revenues: '108905.0', profits: '10477.0' }
        ];

        var obj = {
            scrollModel: { autoFit: true },
            numberCell: {show: false},
            title: "Checkbox selections",
            selectionModel: { type: null },
            pasteModel: { on: false },
            height: 'flex',
            pageModel: { type: "local", rPP: 10 },
            colModel:
            [
                { title: "ID", width: 100, dataType: "integer", dataIndx: "id" },
                { title: "Company", width: 220, dataType: "string", dataIndx: "company" },
                { title: "Revenues ($ millions)", width: 180, dataType: "float", align: "right", dataIndx: "revenues" },
                { title: "Profits ($ millions)", width: 170, dataType: "float", align: "right", dataIndx: "profits" },
                { title: "", dataIndx: "state", maxWidth: 30, minWidth: 30, align: "center",
                    cb: { header: true, all: false },
                    type: 'checkBoxSelection', cls: 'ui-state-default', resizable: false, sortable: false, editable: false,
                    display_checkbox: false
                }
            ],
            toolbar: {
                items: [{
                    type: 'button',
                    label: 'Get Row ID of selected rows',
                    listeners: [{ 'click': function () {

                        var $grid = $(this).closest('.pq-grid');
                        var selarray = $grid.pqGrid('selection', { type: 'row', method: 'getSelection' });
                                      var ids = [];
                        for (var i = 0, len = selarray.length; i < len; i++) {
                            var rowData = selarray[i].rowData;
                            ids.push(rowData.id);
                        }

                        alert(ids);
                    }
                    }]
                }
                ]
            },
            dataModel: {
                data: data,
                location: "local",
                sorting: "local",
                sortIndx: "profits",
                sortDir: "down"
            }
        };
        var $grid = $("#grid_selection_checkbox").pqGrid(obj);
    });
</script>
<body>
  <div id="grid_selection_checkbox" style="margin:auto;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Once the grid is rendered, jQuery can lookup for the checkboxes.

You can use the [PQ Grid](https://paramquery.com/) classes to select rows.

- `.pq-grid-row` is the class for every row.
- `.pq-grid-oddRow` is the class for odd rows.
- `.pq-grid-title-row` is the class for the title row.

So to get the even rows, you can use the all row selector and the [`.not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector.

To target the checkboxes, use an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

```
// Disable the columns checkboxes (check all)
$(".pq-grid-title-row [type='checkbox']").prop("disabled",true);

// Disable checkboxes on even rows.
$(".pq-grid-row:not(.pq-grid-oddRow) [type='checkbox']").prop("disabled",true);

// Disable checkboxes on odd rows.
$(".pq-grid-oddRow [type='checkbox']").prop("disabled",true);
```

Here is a snippet where the checkboxes on odd rows and the column "check all" are disabled.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <!--jQuery dependencies-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

 <!--ParamQuery Grid files-->
 <!--link rel="stylesheet" href="pqgrid.min.css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="pqgrid.min.js" ></script-->

 <!-- I used CDNs here, since your relative paths to PQ Grid was not working here -->
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pqGrid/2.4.1/pqgrid.min.js"></script>
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pqGrid/2.4.1/pqgrid.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

 <!--Main javscript file to create the paramquery-->
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
        //state of the checkbox and row selection is being saved in state field.
        var data = [
            { id: 1, company: 'Exxon Mobil', revenues: '339938.0', profits: '36130.0' },
            { id: 2, company: 'Wal-Mart Stores', revenues: '315654.0', profits: '11231.0' },
            { id: 3, company: 'Royal Dutch Shell', revenues: '306731.0', profits: '25311.0' },
            { id: 4, company: 'BP', revenues: '267600.0', profits: '22341.0' },
            { id: 5, company: 'General Motors', revenues: '192604.0', profits: '-10567.0' },
            { id: 6, company: 'Chevron', revenues: '189481.0', profits: '14099.0' },
            { id: 7, company: 'DaimlerChrysler', revenues: '186106.3', profits: '3536.3'},
            { id: 8, company: 'Toyota Motor', revenues: '185805.0', profits: '12119.6' },
            { id: 9, company: 'Ford Motor', revenues: '177210.0', profits: '2024.0' },
            { id: 10, company: 'ConocoPhillips', revenues: '166683.0', profits: '13529.0' },
            { id: 11, company: 'General Electric', revenues: '157153.0', profits: '16353.0' },
            { id: 12, company: 'Total', revenues: '152360.7', profits: '15250.0' },
            { id: 13, company: 'ING Group', revenues: '138235.3', profits: '8958.9' },
            { id: 14, company: 'Citigroup', revenues: '131045.0', profits: '24589.0' },
            { id: 15, company: 'AXA', revenues: '129839.2', profits: '5186.5'},
            { id: 16, company: 'Allianz', revenues: '121406.0', profits: '5442.4' },
            { id: 17, company: 'Volkswagen', revenues: '118376.6', profits: '1391.7' },
            { id: 18, company: 'Fortis', revenues: '112351.4', profits: '4896.3' },
            { id: 19, company: 'Crédit Agricole', revenues: '110764.6', profits: '7434.3' },
            { id: 20, company: 'American Intl. Group', revenues: '108905.0', profits: '10477.0' }
        ];

        var obj = {
            scrollModel: { autoFit: true },
            numberCell: {show: false},
            title: "Checkbox selections",
            selectionModel: { type: null },
            pasteModel: { on: false },
            height: 'flex',
            pageModel: { type: "local", rPP: 10 },
            colModel:
            [
                { title: "ID", width: 100, dataType: "integer", dataIndx: "id" },
                { title: "Company", width: 220, dataType: "string", dataIndx: "company" },
                { title: "Revenues ($ millions)", width: 180, dataType: "float", align: "right", dataIndx: "revenues" },
                { title: "Profits ($ millions)", width: 170, dataType: "float", align: "right", dataIndx: "profits" },
                { title: "", dataIndx: "state", maxWidth: 30, minWidth: 30, align: "center",
                    cb: { header: true, all: false },
                    type: 'checkBoxSelection', cls: 'ui-state-default', resizable: false, sortable: false, editable: false,
                    display_checkbox: false
                }
            ],
            toolbar: {
                items: [{
                    type: 'button',
                    label: 'Get Row ID of selected rows',
                    listeners: [{ 'click': function () {

                        var $grid = $(this).closest('.pq-grid');
                        var selarray = $grid.pqGrid('selection', { type: 'row', method: 'getSelection' });
                                      var ids = [];
                        for (var i = 0, len = selarray.length; i < len; i++) {
                            var rowData = selarray[i].rowData;
                            ids.push(rowData.id);
                        }

                        alert(ids);
                    }
                    }]
                }
                ]
            },
            dataModel: {
                data: data,
                location: "local",
                sorting: "local",
                sortIndx: "profits",
                sortDir: "down"
            }
        };
        var $grid = $("#grid_selection_checkbox").pqGrid(obj);
        
        // Disable the columns checkboxes (check all)
        $(".pq-grid-title-row [type='checkbox']").prop("disabled",true);
        
        // Disable checkboxes on odd rows.
        $(".pq-grid-oddRow [type='checkbox']").prop("disabled",true);
        
        
    });
    
    
</script>
<body>
  <div id="grid_selection_checkbox" style="margin:auto;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. This is good. But i meant odd row as an example. I actually want to check some condition for a particular row and disable the checkbox and i want to render the table with the disabled rows. I am sorry if my question was ambiguous.

Comment: And also it is not rendered with checkbox's disabled initially.